# Two types using each other in C++

Tags: c++, types, header, destructor, header-files

In my header file I have a function pointer and a struct:

```
typedef struct _CONTINUE_STATE {
    DWORD CurrentCycle;
    CommandProc* CommandFunc;
    void* Resered;
} CONTINUE_STATE, *PCONTINUE_STATE;
```

--

```
typedef HRESULT (*CommandProc)(SOCKET client, char* command, char* response, CONTINUE_STATE* continueProc);
```

The problem is that CommandProc and CONTINUE_STATE both use each other. The function uses the struct as a argument and the struct uses the function as a member. This causes issues because whichever type is at the top of the header isn't able to find the type it uses.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I know I can use void* for the func type in the struct then cast it later on but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: We really do need a FAQ here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly:

```
typedef struct _CONTINUE_STATE {
    DWORD CurrentCycle;
    CommandProc* CommandFunc;
    void* Resered;
} CONTINUE_STATE, *PCONTINUE_STATE;
```

No need for typedefs, and you should not typedef pointers. So lets make that:

```
struct _CONTINUE_STATE {
    DWORD CurrentCycle;
    CommandProc* CommandFunc;
    void* Resered;
};
```

Next, names begining with an underscorea and an uppercase letter are reserved, so:

```
struct CONTINUE_STATE {
    DWORD CurrentCycle;
    CommandProc* CommandFunc;
    void* Resered;
};
```

And, if you really do need mutually referenced type names, which isn't obvious from your code, and isn't very commonly needed then:

```
struct CONTINUE_STATE {
    DWORD CurrentCycle;
    struct CommandProc * CommandFunc;   // forward declaration
    void* Resered;
};
```

Lastly, by convention type names in C++ are in mixed case, with uppercase being reserved for constants, so:

```
struct ContinueState {
    DWORD CurrentCycle;
    struct CommandProc * CommandFunc;   // forward declaration
    void* Resered;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Forward declare the `struct`:

```
struct _CONTINUE_STATE;
typedef struct _CONTINUE_STATE CONTINUE_STATE, *PCONTINUE_STATE;

typedef HRESULT (*CommandProc)(SOCKET client, char* command, char* response,
                               CONTINUE_STATE* continueProc);

struct _CONTINUE_STATE {
    DWORD CurrentCycle;
    CommandProc* CommandFunc;
    void* Resered;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simply, you can just forward declare the `_CONTINUE_STATE` (a horrific and probably undefined name for a type, by the way) and still use it in the typedef. And you don't need to typedef structs like that in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the pre-declaration.

```
struct CONTINUE_STATE;
typedef HRESULT (*CommandProc)(SOCKET client, char* command, char* response, CONTINUE_STATE* continueProc);

typedef struct _CONTINUE_STATE {
  DWORD CurrentCycle;
  CommandProc* CommandFunc;
  void* Resered;
} CONTINUE_STATE, *PCONTINUE_STATE;
```